# Reorder UserCreationFrom fields from django.contrib.auth and allauth

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-allauth

I am trying to reorder fields in a user sign up form using django.contrib.auth. There seem to be, however, some fields (username, email and password) that I cannot reorder that I think may be coming from django allauth.

settings.py

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'users.forms.UserCreationForm'
```

forms.py

```
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    error_message = UserCreationForm.error_messages.update(
        {
            "duplicate_username": _(
                "This username has already been taken."
            )
        }
    )
    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=12, min_length=4, required=True,
                                widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'placeholder': 'First Name'}))
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=12, min_length=4, required=True,
                               widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=50, help_text='Required. Inform a valid email address.',
                             widget=(forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})))
    password1 = forms.CharField(label=_('Password'),
                                widget=(forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})),
                                help_text=password_validation.password_validators_help_text_html())
    password2 = forms.CharField(label=_('Password Confirmation'), widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}),
                                help_text=_('Just Enter the same password, for confirmation'))
    username = forms.CharField(
        label=_('Username'),
        max_length=150,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={'unique': _("A user with that username already exists.")},
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    )

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]

        try:
            User.objects.get(username=username)
        except User.DoesNotExist:
            return username

        raise ValidationError(
            self.error_messages["duplicate_username"]
        )
```

I am able to reorder first and last name fields but these always come below username, email, and password.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the order in which fields are structured with `field_order`.

Like so:

```py
class UserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):
    
    [.. fields ..]

    class Meta(UserCreationForm.Meta):
        model = User
        fields = ('username', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password1', 'password2',)

    field_order = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2','first_name', 'last_name']
```

Comment: Apologies I should have mentioned that I had tried that but it has no effect